# Points duplicating when previewing layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am trying to display a GeoPackage of points with OpenLayers from GeoServer; however when I try and render the map the points appear to be duplicated.

When I generate a CSV with Layer Preview in GeoServer, the points appear to be correct, but when I view the PNG or OpenLayers they appear to be duplicated in a repeating pattern, as shown in this image:

[image: Duplicated points]

Why may this be the case? I have tried everything from disabling tile caching to changing the projection (I'm using ESPG:4326) but nothing seems to work.

**EDIT:**

Below is a sample of the CSV file exported from Layer Preview in GeoServer.

```
FID,geom,set,name
CigaretteCards.1,POINT (5271.757121028228 -2283.97272121377),FamousGunslingers,Frank Heck
CigaretteCards.2,POINT (5442.08821142518 -1988.5248326741105),FamousGunslingers,Otis Miller Boys
CigaretteCards.3,POINT (5150.946445957355 -1633.9873664265206),FamousGunslingers,Jack Hall Gang
CigaretteCards.4,POINT (7259.989834917378 -2317.2255604907045),FamousGunslingers,Butcher Brothers
CigaretteCards.5,POINT (6361.923945380633 -3788.005818581249),FamousGunslingers,Flaco Hernandez
```

Comment: If you zoom in do the repeated ones disappear?

Comment: The image provided is just the static PNG image from Geoserver, but in the OpenLayers view they do disappear as I zoom in.

Comment: I'd put a base map behind the points, but it looks like you are looking at number of world's at that zoom level

Comment: That's what I tried with the OpenLayers preview; a base map behind. The base map works fine when you zoom out then the points appear to duplicate to other locations on the map.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some of the rows of the CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates are clearly not in EPSG:4326, map wrapping is likely porting over the points that are beyond -180°/180° into the sane range.
I see two options:

- Give them a true projected CRS, e.g., EPSG:32632, and reconfigure the layer from scratch
- Disable map wrapping in the WMS settings

Comment: Thank you, disabling map wrapping fixed it. I wasn't sure what CRS to use since it was a fictional map, but I may consider choosing a projected CRS.